# Get mouse position in Javascript without using a onmousemove event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouse

I basically just want to return the current position of the mouse and without needed to refer to an event.

I am completely at a loss on how to do this, I can only make it work using events, is it possible to do it statically without needed a movement to occur first?

Comment: Can't take control of mouse or cursor away from user. if you could there would be massive abuse of it. You can however simulate mouse events

Comment: Does it always require me to take control of the mouse just to get its current position